# Cross reference a data table and sum figures given a column and multiple row references

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of data. The first column holds all the names of clients. The top row holds the month (several columns can contain the same month). Within the table itself is all the sales figures for that particular client for that particular month.

```
            Jan Jan Feb Feb Feb Mar April
client a    500 600 800 100 400 900 750
client b    750 500 300 700 900 850 456
client c    650 780 903 604 502 205 250
```

What I need to do is have a formula that will essentially find client b then add up all the Feb sales. I've tried the likes of =VLOOKUP("client b",sumif(a1:a5,"Feb",a1:d5)) but I can't seem to get it to work.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUMIF($B$1:$H$1,"Feb",INDEX($B$2:$H$4,MATCH("client b",$A$2:$A$4,0),0))`

Slight change to use `INDEX(,MATCH(),)` to find the row of data you want, passing 0 for the column argument to get all of the row.

Comment: Perfect!! You're a life saver!! Thank you